# Height Proporcional ao Width, responsivo

Tags: css

Abaixo temos um layout grid, fluido, sem imagens. O que gostaria agora é que o height fosse proporcionalmente responsivo ao width.

https://codepen.io/johnquimera/pen/aGZaVY

```css
    .my-prop-grid {
        width: 46%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
      
        height: 336px;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-main {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-wrap {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: #fff;
        color: #666666;
        border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 30px 0;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="my-prop-grid">
        <div class="my-grid-main">
            <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                <div class="my-grid-inner">
                    <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at eleifend leo.</a></h3>
                    <p>Mauris in metus vitae libero laoreet malesuada vel a turpis. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="my-prop-grid">
        <div class="my-grid-main">
            <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                <div class="my-grid-inner">
                    <h3><a href="#">Praesent eu ex ligula. Aenean hendrerit pretium odio, nec pretium nisl ornare vitae.</a></h3>
                    <p>Vestibulum vel velit non tortor tristique fermentum ac et turpis. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## EDIT

Para fazer isso vc pode usar o *técnica* do `padding-top` [Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre isso](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp) Não é muito recomendado, mas como vc presia manter esse *aspect ratio* esse exemplo pode resolver.

Como vc falou que que que a altura seja 50% da largura e a sua largura é de 46%, basta colocar um `padding-top:23%` que vc vai ter o que precisa. No entanto vc precisa alinha novamente o conteúdo dentro do box. E para isso precisai usar `float`, `cleafix` e `transform`, e fazer uns @media para ficar bem responsivo.

**OBS:** Não mexi no html, só no CSS, deixei os comentário no código

Veja o resultado no exemplo abaixo.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.my-prop-grid {
        width: 46%; /* 100% é 46% logo o height tem que ser 23% */
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;

    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-main {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-wrap {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: #fff;
        color: #666666;
        border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
        padding-top: 23%; /* esse padding de 23% vai manter o aspecto de 50% da largura que é 46% */
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner {
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 10% 10px 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        transform: translateY(-50%);  /* alinha o conteúdo na vertical */
    }
    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner::after { /* clearfix do float */
        content:"";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }

    /* tratamento responsivos*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
        .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner {
            transform: translateY(-30%);
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
        .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner {
            transform: translateY(-20%);
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px){
        .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner {
            transform: translateY(-12%);
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">

        <div class="my-prop-grid">
            <div class="my-grid-main">
                <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                    <div class="my-grid-inner">
                        <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at eleifend leo.</a></h3>
                        <p>Mauris in metus vitae libero laoreet malesuada vel a turpis. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="my-prop-grid">
            <div class="my-grid-main">
                <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                    <div class="my-grid-inner">
                        <h3><a href="#">Praesent eu ex ligula. Aenean hendrerit pretium odio, nec pretium nisl ornare vitae.</a></h3>
                        <p>Vestibulum vel velit non tortor tristique fermentum ac et turpis. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

---

Como vc não colocou demais detalhes ou condições a coisa mais básica a se fazer e tirar o valor fixo do height dessa classe e colocar com auto `.my-prop-grid { height: auto;}`

Veja como fica no exemplo. Agora sem altura fixa o tamanho vai se ajustar conforme o conteúdo que está dentro.

```css
    
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.my-prop-grid {
        width: 46%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
      
        height: auto;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-main {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-wrap {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: #fff;
        color: #666666;
        border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 30px 0;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="container">

        <div class="my-prop-grid">
            <div class="my-grid-main">
                <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                    <div class="my-grid-inner">
                        <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at eleifend leo.</a></h3>
                        <p>Mauris in metus vitae libero laoreet malesuada vel a turpis. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="my-prop-grid">
            <div class="my-grid-main">
                <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                    <div class="my-grid-inner">
                        <h3><a href="#">Praesent eu ex ligula. Aenean hendrerit pretium odio, nec pretium nisl ornare vitae.</a></h3>
                        <p>Vestibulum vel velit non tortor tristique fermentum ac et turpis. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

*Artigo sobre essa técnica:* http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: em localhost eu já tinha testado isso, mas queria que ao menos o height inicial fosse do tamanho do width.

Comment: @JohnQuimera qual proporção mais precisamente vc precisa? Vc quer que tenha 1/3 da largura? 50% da largura? 3/4 da largura?

Comment: pode ser 50%, eu estava pensando se isso não funcionária com aspect ratio, mas como não tem imagem, não sei dizer.

Comment: @JohnQuimera cara olha no início da minha resposta o **Edit** que eu fiz, com essa técnica vc consegue manter a proporção altura largura, testa ai e me fala.

Comment: muito bom, eu tinha decidido que iria usar isso com as grids do bootstrap, se possível com uma proporção de 880x660.

Comment: poderia me ajudar com outra pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/300239/95735

Answer (score 1):

O ideal é que você sete um `max-height` além do `height`, já que você quer que a altura tenha `336px` no máximo. Ficaria:

```
height: 100%;
max-height: 336px;
```

```css
.my-prop-grid {
        width: 46%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
      
         height: 100%;
        max-height: 336px;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-main {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-wrap {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: #fff;
        color: #666666;
        border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 30px 0;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="my-prop-grid">
        <div class="my-grid-main">
            <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                <div class="my-grid-inner">
                    <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at eleifend leo.</a></h3>
                    <p>Mauris in metus vitae libero laoreet malesuada vel a turpis. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="my-prop-grid">
        <div class="my-grid-main">
            <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                <div class="my-grid-inner">
                    <h3><a href="#">Praesent eu ex ligula. Aenean hendrerit pretium odio, nec pretium nisl ornare vitae.</a></h3>
                    <p>Vestibulum vel velit non tortor tristique fermentum ac et turpis. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

Um outra alternativa é usando jQuery para manter a proporção das `div`s e igualar a altura quando forem diferentes:

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){

   var gridPr = $(".my-prop-grid");
   var gridWt = gridPr.width();
   var gridHt = gridPr.height();

   var gridMn = $(".my-grid-main");

   // manter a proporção 538x336 = 1,601190476190476
   $(".my-prop-grid")
   .css("height", gridWt/1.601190476190476+"px");

   // loop para manter as divs na mesma altura
   var gridAt = 0;
   gridMn.each(function(){
      if($(this).height() > gridAt) gridAt = $(this).height();
   });

   $(".my-prop-grid")
   .css("height", gridAt+"px");

});
```

```css
.my-prop-grid {
        width: 46%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
      
        /*height: 336px;*/
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-main {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-wrap {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: #fff;
        color: #666666;
        border: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
    }

    .my-prop-grid .my-grid-inner {
        margin: auto;
        padding: 30px 0;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .container {
        max-width: 1170px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <div class="my-prop-grid">
        <div class="my-grid-main">
            <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                <div class="my-grid-inner">
                    <h3><a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus at eleifend leo.</a></h3>
                    <p>Mauris in metus vitae libero laoreet malesuada vel a turpis. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="my-prop-grid">
        <div class="my-grid-main">
            <div class="my-grid-wrap">
                <div class="my-grid-inner">
                    <h3><a href="#">Praesent eu ex ligula. Aenean hendrerit pretium odio, nec pretium nisl ornare vitae.</a></h3>
                    <p>Vestibulum vel velit non tortor tristique fermentum ac et turpis. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: interessante, há algo sabe? gostaria de que se possível, o height não fosse definido, mas que tivesse o mesmo tamanho do width.

Comment: Então no caso seria um quadrado? Só com CSS não creio ser possível porque as dimensões width e height da tela são diferentes.

Comment: pode ser que sim, acho que isso ficaria bem, o que você achar que fica bem, está bem.

Comment: Acrescentei na resposta uma solução com jQuery.

Comment: eu vacilei, desde do começo, isso é para ser utilizado com as grids do bootstrap, testei aqui e funciona, queria manter uma proporção de 880x660

Comment: gostaria de manter uma proporção de 880x660, como fazer para calcula-la?

Comment: Vc calcula a proporção dividindo o maior pelo menor: 880/660 = 1,333333333333333

Comment: Ou o menor pelo maior: 660/880 = 0,75... significa que o menor é 0,75 do tamanho do maior.